# Dynamically changing object keys with lodash map keys or any other javascript methods(NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

This is my json object:

```
{ 
excels:
   [ { field1: 'Mohamed',
       field2: '123456789',
       field3: 'Sameer',
       field4: 'Chennai',
       field5: 'Chennai',
       field6: 'Asia',
       field7: '11111',
       field8: '10-10-1990',
       field9: 'sameer@gmail.com'},

     { field1: 'Ganesh',
       field2: '987654321',
       field3: 'Pandiyan',
       field4: 'Chennai',
       field5: 'Chennai',
       field6: 'Asia',
       field7: '11111',
       field8: '10-10-1990',
       field9: 'ganesh@gmail.com' } ],
  header:
   { '1': 'firstName',
     '2': 'gsm',
     '3': 'lastName',
     '4': 'street',
     '5': 'city',
     '6': 'region',
     '7': 'postcode',
     '8': 'dob',
     '9': 'email' } 

}
```

I want to make above json like this:

```
[{firstName:Mohamed;gsm:123456789;lastName:Sameer;street:Chennai;city:Chennai;region:Asia;postcode:11111;dob:10-10-1990;email:sameer@gmail.com},{firstName:Ganesh;gsm:987654321;lastName:Pandiyan;street:Chennai;city:Chennai;region:Asia;postcode:11111;dob:10-10-1990;email:ganesh@gmail.com}]
```

But One condition,
in case if my json header objects looks like:

```
header: 
   { '1': 'lastName',
     '2': 'gsm',
     '3': 'firstName',
     '4': 'street',
     '5': 'city',
     '6': 'region',
     '7': 'postcode',
     '8': 'dob',
     '9': 'email' }
```

P.S: I am changing firstName and lastName order

I want to make above json like this:

```
[{firstName:Sameer;gsm:123456789;lastName:Mohamed;street:Chennai;city:Chennai;region:Asia;postcode:11111;dob:10-10-1990;email:sameer@gmail.com},{firstName:Pandiyan;gsm:987654321;lastName:Ganesh;street:Chennai;city:Chennai;region:Asia;postcode:11111;dob:10-10-1990;email:ganesh@gmail.com}]
```

**See the firstname and lastname**

How to do this? is it possible to do this with any js method?

Comment: Its completely possible. But what have you tried?

Comment: I am getting this json, but i dont know how to make structure like this, so only i am looking for solution?

Comment: Have a look at reduce on object, use empty object as statrting value, iterate on your header object and build up your result from each entry of your excel array

Comment: @ilmrions can you post some piece of code! it will be really helpful to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with performing some simple array/object manipulations,

```
var result = source.excels.map((details) =>
  Object.keys(details).reduce((a, b) =>
    (a[source.header[b.replace('field', '')]] =
      details[b], a), {}));

console.log(result);
// result would contain [{firstName:'Mohamed',gsm:123456789, ......
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xwux1y9z/)

Things to learn here [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**Note:** We cannot rely on orders when it comes to dealing an object. That's the reason why I have relied on the key string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883754/insert-datas-into-mysqlsequelize-using-javascriptnodejs-based-on-radio-butto/47884222#47884222 help me

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using native [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods:

```
const persons = { 
  excels:
     [ { field1: 'Mohamed',
         field2: '123456789',
         field3: 'Sameer',
         field4: 'Chennai',
         field5: 'Chennai',
         field6: 'Asia',
         field7: '11111',
         field8: '10-10-1990',
         field9: 'sameer@gmail.com'},

       { field1: 'Ganesh',
         field2: '987654321',
         field3: 'Pandiyan',
         field4: 'Chennai',
         field5: 'Chennai',
         field6: 'Asia',
         field7: '11111',
         field8: '10-10-1990',
         field9: 'ganesh@gmail.com' } ],
    header:
     { '1': 'firstName',
       '2': 'gsm',
       '3': 'lastName',
       '4': 'street',
       '5': 'city',
       '6': 'region',
       '7': 'postcode',
       '8': 'dob',
       '9': 'email' } 
}

const personKeys = Object.keys(persons.header)

const formattedPersons = persons.excels.map((p) => {
    const formattedPerson = personKeys.reduce((newPerson, currentKey) => {
    newPerson[persons.header[currentKey]] = p[`field${currentKey}`]

    return newPerson
  }, {})


  return formattedPerson;
})
```