# Insert datas into mysql(Sequelize) using javascript(NodeJS) based on radio button value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this below json object

```
{
    "phoneno": [
    {
        "field1": "Mohamed",
        "field2": "123456789",
        "field3": "Sameer"
    },
    {
        "field1": "Ganesh",
        "field2": "987654321",
        "field3": "Pandiyan" 
     }
  ],
    "sender": "ifelse",
    "message": "test"
}
```

I am showing this JSON in UI using **ANGULARJS** ng-repeat, also I am displaying radio button dynamically, see the below image

[image]

see there is radio button checked, in this columns, I have two mobile numbers,
so I want to make the final object like this:

```
[
  {"phoneno" : 123456789 ; "sender" : "ifelse" ; "message" : "test"},
  {"phoneno" : 987654321 ; "sender" : "ifelse" ; "message" : "test"}
]
```

For example, if I got this type of JSON:

```
{
    "phoneno": [
    {
        "field1": "123456789",
        "field2": "Mohamed",
        "field3": "Sameer"
    },
    {
        "field1": "987654321",
        "field2": "Ganesh",
        "field3": "Pandiyan" 
     }
  ],
    "sender": "ifelse",
    "message": "test"
}
```

now again

I am showing this JSON in UI using ng-repeat, also I am displaying radio button dynamically, see the below image

[image]

see there is radio button checked, in this columns, i have two mobile numbers,
so I want to make the final object like this:

```
[
  {"phoneno" : 123456789 ; "sender" : "ifelse" ; "message" : "test"},
  {"phoneno" : 987654321 ; "sender" : "ifelse" ; "message" : "test"}
]
```

if i got this type of object, I can bulk insert into mysql with the help of sequelize.

How to done this?

my api.js ( i did not still code, looking for the solution)

```
exports.sendFile2Sms = function (req, res) {

};
```

Comment: Bind radio buttons to corresponding column index/name or just use ngChange handlers and pas the index/name as a parameter.

Comment: Can you post some solution? it will be really helpful to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079286/sequelize-bulkcreate-returns-null-value-for-primary-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be helpful to you, In your data, you should mention which is column selected for example `field2` is selected means you should append that to your JSON data.

In your case, I have added new key to find which is column `"selected_radio":"field2"` like this you should do the same on your front end

and here is the angular part of change your JSON data

```js
var data={
    "phoneno": [
    {
        "field1": "Mohamed",
        "field2": "123456789",
        "field3": "Sameer"
    },
    {
        "field1": "Ganesh",
        "field2": "987654321",
        "field3": "Pandiyan" 
     }
  ],
    "sender": "ifelse",
    "message": "test",
    "selected_radio":"field2"
};
var new_data=[];
_.each(data.phoneno,function(obj){
new_data.push({"phoneno":obj[data.selected_radio],"sender":data.sender,"message":data.message});
})
console.log(new_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct , if i selected second column radio button, i want to add key in json called  "selected_radio":"field2